# Could not get pipeline: canShowEditor (domain: ExperienceEditor)

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, habitat

I am getting the following error after installing the Habitat solution for Sitecore 9, from https://github.com/sitecore/habitat/tree/feature/v9 , and pointing it at a clean Sitecore install...

Could not get pipeline: canShowEditor (domain: ExperienceEditor)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not get pipeline: canShowEditor (domain: ExperienceEditor)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Could not get pipeline: canShowEditor (domain: ExperienceEditor)]
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +283
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.CanShowEditor.ExecuteCanShowEditor.Run(CanShowEditorPipelineEventArgs canShowEditorPipelineArgs) +93
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.GetExperienceEditorRibbon.WebEditStateProcessor.CheckState() +72
   (Object , Object ) +19
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.GetExperienceEditorRibbon.ExecuteGetExperienceEditorRibbon.Run(GetExperienceEditorRibbonArgs args) +93
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonPageExtender.Insert() +58
   Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.PageExtenders.Process(RenderLayoutArgs args) +263
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Layouts.PageContext.BuildControlTree(Object sender, EventArgs e) +209
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +11854916
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1110
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved. I needed to install Sitecore 9.0.2 and then configure the Habitat solution to point to that. Initially I was using a Sitecore 9.0.1 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have resolved this issue, but for other developers who might encountered this problem; I had encountered similar issue while installing habitat in Sitecore 9-Update 1. Spent few hours trying to resolve/troubleshoot it, but ended up installing a vanilla Sitecore 9-Update 2 instead using habitat scripts (install-xp0.ps1) because upgrade process from U1 to U2 will definitely take more time.